# How to add multiple columns in Apache Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

Here is my input data with four columns with space as the delimiter. I want to add the second and third column and print the result

```
sachin 200 10 2
sachin 900 20 2
sachin 500 30 3
Raju 400 40 4
Mike 100 50 5
Raju 50 60 6
```

My code is in the mid way

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
def getLineInfo(lines):
    spLine = lines.split(' ')
    name = str(spLine[0])
    cash = int(spLine[1])
    cash2 = int(spLine[2])
    cash3 = int(spLine[3])
    return (name,cash,cash2)
myFile = sc.textFile("D:\PYSK\cash.txt")
rdd = myFile.map(getLineInfo)
print rdd.collect()
```

From here I got the result as

```
[('sachin', 200, 10), ('sachin', 900, 20), ('sachin', 500, 30), ('Raju', 400, 40
), ('Mike', 100, 50), ('Raju', 50, 60)]
```

Now the final result I need is as below, adding the 2nd and 3rd column and display the remaining fields

```
sachin 210 2
sachin 920 2
sachin 530 3
Raju 440 4
Mike 150 5
Raju 110 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
def getLineInfo(lines):
    spLine = lines.split(' ')
    name = str(spLine[0])
    cash = int(spLine[1])
    cash2 = int(spLine[2])
    cash3 = int(spLine[3])
    return (name, cash + cash2, cash3)
```

Comment: It Worked . Thanks . One more question - Once we have data in RDD , can we do some manipulation on specific data 
Example: I have in RDD  [('sachin', 200, 10), ('Raju', 900, 20)] . How to Fetch 3rd column only , I mean 10 and 20

Comment: @SachinSukumaran You should accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: To fetch columns in different rows. I recommend you to read about: `reduceByKey()` method.